# Deleting the versions of every file in an Amazon S3 bucket older than X days

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

I find it strange that after looking everywhere I don't find any tool to delete all the versions of a file older than X days (not the actual file) of a S3 bucket that has versioning enabled.
I would believe this is a very common issue because without it the buckets with time would become huge.

Is there any existing solution (even commercial)?

If there is no ready made way, could you point me to some info or give me suggestions on how to code this myself in C#? I guess I have to use recursion for this kind of problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the amazon s3 API, you can do that.
I use AmazonS3Client + DeleteObjectRequest method on amazon SDK:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/DeleteObjectRequest.html

Should really be straightforward.

Hope it helps

Comment: I hoped for a more detailed answer with a short snippet. I don't want to risk my data by making some newbie mistake, since I never programmed for S3 Api. But this at least point to the minimum information so I'll award you the bounty. But if you have some more help/suggestions please let me know.